ZFS System update-grub not detecting updated kernel images in /boot Ubuntu 20.04
I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04 and every time I do an apt upgrade with a new kernel version, and reboot the system, I seem to be stuck on kernel version 5.4.0-137.
The system is two drives, with a VFAT partition for EFI, and a ZFS bpool and ZFS rpool (mirrored)
I have an additional drive that is just standard EXT4.
When I do an update-grub command it finds kernel version 5.4.0-137 but it doesn't find the latest kernel version 5.4.0-182 even though it is in /boot as expected:
root@trintimoto:/boot# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-137-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.4.0-137-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu
device-mapper: reload ioctl on osprober-linux-nvme0n1p4  failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed.
device-mapper: reload ioctl on osprober-linux-nvme1n1p4  failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
root@trintimoto:/boot# ls -altr
total 192375
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root       512 Dec 31  1969 efi2
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root       512 Dec 31  1969 efi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-------  1 root root   4760076 Apr 26 04:36 System.map-5.4.0-182-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    237713 Apr 26 04:36 config-5.4.0-182-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  13689608 Apr 26 05:20 vmlinuz-5.4.0-182-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 May 14 10:09 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-182-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 May 14 10:09 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-182-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 May 14 10:11 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-182-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 May 14 10:11 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-182-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 183080433 May 15 13:40 initrd.img-5.4.0-182-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root        16 May 15 13:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root        28 May 15 13:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root       512 May 15 13:50 grub

I've followed several similar issues, but have found now solution.
zfs-dkms was not installed, so I just installed it, and it rebuilt all the kernal versions with headers, but update grub still only picks up version 5.4.0.137.  (which I don't know exactly where that is located by the way)
dkms status shows the following:
root@trintimoto:/boot# dkms status
nvidia, 525.60.13, 5.4.0-137-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 525.60.13, 5.4.0-182-generic, x86_64: installed
zfs, 0.8.3, 5.4.0-137-generic, x86_64: installed
zfs, 0.8.3, 5.4.0-162-generic, x86_64: installed
zfs, 0.8.3, 5.4.0-171-generic, x86_64: installed
zfs, 0.8.3, 5.4.0-182-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

I have seen it might have something to do with 10_linux_zfs located in /etc/grub.d and potentially a conflict with xen.  I've also seen issues with a missing version_find_latest in the 10_linux_zfs script causing problems.  (Which my 10_linux_zfs does call version_find_latest which I don't seem to have installed)
If anyone has any ideas why update_grub isn't seeing my latest kernel version, please let me know.
Thanks!
Pete

After tinkering with it, I had somehow managed to break the grub boot completely.  Not I was completely stuck, since it was not even booting into grub. (just would fall back to bios)
I fixed this by grabbing the recovery ZFSBootMenu image from:
https://docs.zfsbootmenu.org/en/v2.3.x/
and making a bootable usb drive with it.  With this I was able to boot my system.  Then I fixed the EFI boot by following the instructions here:
https://docs.zfsbootmenu.org/en/v2.3.x/guides/ubuntu/uefi.html#install-and-configure-zfsbootmenu
A couple of hints:  Instead of zroot/ROOT for the zfs set I used rpool/ROOT since that was my pool name
Also when working with efibootmgr the $BOOT_DISK and $BOOT_PART need to be the actual drive in my case "/dev/nvme0n1" and partition "2"
I also used the wiki for efibootmgr to remove the older boot images and set to make sure the active are active.
This wiki is located here:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
